# how I iterate coulmns in 3d array in a wide dimension in c?

Tags: arrays, c, 3d

i'm looking for a loop logic to iterate over all possible columns in a 3d array of size 4X4X4.
I need to check eacgh cell with a ceratin color,
meaning:
[image]

Comment: Do you know how to iterate over a "1D" array? How about iterating over all values of a "2D" array? These are the "columns" you're having, so that's all you need even for your "3D" array.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Could you provide an example of the sequence of elements you'd like to get our of the iteration?